# Why isn't hydra being disconnected?

Tags: ssh, tcp, hydra

I have SSHD running on port 5800 on some machine. (It is a my machine at home.)
If I run this manually in a terminal:

```
# ssh someIP -p 5800
```

The connection is lost because I am disconnected after 3 consecutive mistakes. OK.

Now I do a brute force with hydra on this port with ssh as specified service and password root.
It seems to run and tries passwords, but now I wonder why I am not disconnected this way. Is this because hydra instantiates a new connection for every new password, closes it after trying the password, and opens a new connection again for the next password attempt?

Comment: I guess it tries as much passwords it can and reconnects whenever disconnected. You can check `sshd` logs on the target machine.